# How link a menu group in magento (via blocks/.phtml files)

Tags: magento

I have created a mega menu group. but i stuck at relating it to file.

All i can see form a default one is

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="megamenu_left" as="megamenu_left" translate="label">
   <label>Left Megamenu</label>
</block>
```

In Home page(Backend > Design Section):

```
<reference name="megamenu_left">
    <block type="megamenu/list" name="megamenu.list.theme" as="megaMenuLeft" template="sm/megamenu/megamenu-left.phtml">
        <action method="setConfig">
            <values>  
                <group_id>2</group_id>
                <theme>2</theme>
            </values>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

And in home page Front view:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('megamenu_left') ?>
```

Things i didn't get is **name="megamenu.list.theme"** and how this is rendering.

**EDITED**

how is 'megamenu_left' from xml above is linked with a menu group i created on the backend. The menu group i created on backend just have a name and 'enable/disable' option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but the second XML bit is going to look for the reference "megamenu_left" found in the first XML part, and insert the block at that position.

The block itself has the full name "megamenu.list.theme" in the layout, with the optional shortname "megaMenuLeft".  It will render the template file "sm/megamenu/megamenu-left.phtml" which will be positioned in the active theme folder such as "app/design/frontend/theme/..".

The template will be using the PHP block from module "megamenu/Block/List.php" so any $this->functionName() calls or variables accessed from within the function comes from that block.

The frontpage will load the block by name from the first part of XML, which in turn will get the content from the second part XML since it's a reference, meaning it will insert itself in the first XML.

Comment: how is 'megamenu_left' from xml above is linked with a menu group i created on the backend. The menu group i created on backend just have a name and 'enable/disable' option.

Comment: Well the megamenu/Block/List.php file somehow uses the info set as options `<group_id>2</group_id>` and `<theme>2</theme>` to figure that out.  Impossible to know exactly how it does the connection without seeing the full code listing for that `Block/List.php` file.

Comment: Ok great, last query: via group id i can differentiate the menu-groups. But on changing the reference name and group id(for anther group of menu) and copying all other things as it is, Renders the menu group 3(group i created) on original and this new one.